# Value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,28] JODA time

Tags: android

My code to calculate remaining days for next birthday gives me following error when I use leap year i.e.; when used with 29th feb

*ERROR**Value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,28]

Please help me in this problem...

```
public int getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(){
          Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
          int currentYear=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          int currentMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          int birthYear=currentYear;
          int birthMonth=Integer.parseInt(m);
          int birthDay=Integer.parseInt(d);
          if (birthMonth<currentMonth) {
            birthYear=birthYear+1;
        }
          DateTime birthDate=new DateTime(birthYear,birthMonth,birthDay,0, 0);

          DateTime currentDate=DateTime.now();
          Period datePeriod=new Period(currentDate,birthDate,PeriodType.days());
          PeriodFormatter periodFormatter=new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
          .appendDays().appendSuffix("").toFormatter();       

          return Integer.parseInt(periodFormatter.print(datePeriod));
      }
```

Comment: What year are you trying with? Please note that leap years aren't leap years every 400 years. 2000 wasn't a leap year for example.

Comment: 29th feb 1988 is the data I am trying with.

Comment: Ok, weird. I don't know what the problem might be.

Comment: Could it be the `birthYear+1` part? Is that taking you to construct a `DateTime(1989, 2, 29)` ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in Java's `Calendar` the months are numbered from 0, but in `Joda Time` they are numbered from 1.

So in your example you pass `2` as the month, which is `March` according to the `Calendar` class, but it is interpreted as `February` by the Joda Time framework.

To solve it just add 1 to the month you get from `Calendar` when passing it to Joda.